# Can I post a question I've already asked, but with more detail?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I asked a question in ELL and got one detailed answer which I accepted. But later, I realized I still have queries and that that answer raised further questions. Also, my original question remains unsolved. I followed it up with some of my own research, but I am still confused.

Can I post that question again in a better way and with more details?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The big lesson learned here is to furnish as many details as you can when you first ask your question. When fewer details are furnished, the answers won’t be specifically tailored to your main concerns. We can’t read your mind.

As for what to do now, I’d say that it’s okay to ask a follow-on question, but, to avoid having it closed as a duplicate:

- Make sure your new question asks about something that the previous question didn’t. (It’s okay if it starts the same, but be very clear about how you are asking about something this time that was not asked about last time.)
- Go ahead and link to your prior question in your new question, so people can read both.

It looks like you’ve already [done all this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/177614/struggling-with-comma-usage-in-essential-and-non-essential-clauses), but I’ve left an answer here in case anyone else wonders about this same thing.

Thanks for asking on meta, and thanks for asking such a well-detailed follow-on question. I’ve upvoted it.

A couple footnotes:

1. If you ever ask a question that didn’t attract the answer you had hoped for, you can consider using a bounty. You can read about bounties [here in the Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).
2. Also, if you only get one answer, and it doesn’t answer all your concerns, there is nothing wrong with waiting a week or so before you an accept an answer. Occasionally, people accept answers [too soon](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer), which might prevent better answers from being added.

I don’t think those really apply in this particular example, but that may be helpful information for the general case.